# Plasma 5 Fonts Not Working

Tags: kde, fonts, 16.04, plasma

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and installed the `kubuntu-desktop` package in order to take advantage of KDE5.

However, the fonts and similar visual systems are completely refusing to work, even after being set properly:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there any way I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when i installed kubuntu on ubuntu 16.04.

While these font settings do not seem to work, you can change the font by going to :

**System Settings>Appearance>Application Style>GNOME Application Style**

There is a font setting which you may change and the effect will take place the next time you log in.